# Random System.NotSupportedException on WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Sporadically, I receive an error in my WP7 Silverlight application. The error is a random "System.NotSupportedException". This error is thrown occassionally when the following code is executed:

```
// 1. Build the url
string serviceURL = "http://www.mydomain.com/service.svc/param1/param2";

// 2. Asynchronously execute the query using HttpWebRequest instead of WebClient. There is a UI performance issue with the WebClient currently
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(MyService_Completed), request);

...

private void MyService_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

I have verified that the URL I am sending is correct. Please note, that this request is part of my view model, which may have other network requests fired off at the same time. I have no idea why this happens ocassionally. Can anybody point out any potential reasons?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens, make sure you look at the View Detail part of the exception report. It might be that your service is refusing connection or the data passed is invalid. `NotSupported` is a very general exception that covers many possible situations.

Answer (score 0):

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053197/httpwebrequest-leads-me-to-system-notsupportedexception) has been asked previously. If you look at the comments the original poster added to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053197/httpwebrequest-leads-me-to-system-notsupportedexception/4053915#4053915), he claims to have solved the problem by replacing

```
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(MyService_Completed), request);
```

with

```
request.BeginGetResponse( MyService_Completed, request);
```